# JIRA traceability metrix report for cloud instance

Tags: jira

Does anyone knows how to get traceability matrix report in JIRA Cloud instance? Several good plugins there but all are only supported to the server instances, not for the cloud ? I have already installed QMetry JIRA plugin for test cases, if anyone tried a different solution for traceability matrix reports other than using a plugin, it would help me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are a few options that you could test for your need!

1. [All-in-One Reports for JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.kaanha.reports/cloud/overview)
2. [Traceability Matrix and Link Graph](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.kostebekteknoloji.plugins.jira.jira-traceability-matrix/server/overviewhttps://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.kostebekteknoloji.plugins.jira.jira-traceability-matrix/server/overview)
3. [Custom reporting with Midori](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-pdf-view-plugin/documentation/#scripting)

Not just these, there are quite a few custom approaches on getting this done, by implementing your own code on the results that you gain from JQL's instead. There is this page on Atlassian, that you must go through to get some hints and pointers for your implementation, or to choose from something that already exists.

[Check this discussion!](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/What-reporting-capability-is-available-from-JIRA/qaq-p/178515)

Hope this helps!